# Swift -Does the Bonjour NSNetServiceBrowser have a peer limit larger then MCSession's 8?

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour, mcsession

Using a `MCSession`, the session can only have [8 devices connected](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcsession) to it:

> Sessions currently support up to 8 peers, including the local peer

I need way more than 8 peers. I came across this [apple forums dev thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117402) where someone asked a similar question and an Apple engineer named **eskimo** said that it can be achieved using `NSNetService` and its `includesPeerToPeer flag` or the `Bonjour browser`.

I've seen a bunch of people ask questions on how to get around the `MCSession` 8 peer limit but I haven't seen anyone recommend what **eskimo** recommended. I also haven't found any blog posts with sample code to support what he said. His answer was posted on 6/5/19 so it's very recent.

**If this is possible what is the peer limit if there is one?**

[image]

Comment: I think they are suggesting that you build your own discovery service using Bonjour. The number of peers would then only be limited by your own code.

Comment: You may have better luck posting this to another StackExchanges site: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) which describes itself as "Ask Different is a question and answer site for power users of Apple hardware and software. It only takes a minute to sign up."

Comment: @clearlight I didn’t understand why this got downvoted. I think it’s a legit question especially since so many people ask how to get around the MCSession 8 peer limit. I have only found 1 Obj-C answers that leads you in the right direction but it’s still in Obj-C not Swift. This questions let’s others know that there are other ways to do achieve other then MCSession.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. However it's not really a coding question. It's about library or offsite code or big picture stuff and those aren't well suited for this site. And I referred you to a site that is probably better for a question like yours. The downvote was probably to discourage people from wasting time on your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For what ever it's worth, Lance, I bumped into your question while working the Close Votes queue. Don't know why it ended up there. And I didn't vote to close it myself.

Comment: @clearlight I know you didn’t downvote it. It got downvoted 5 minute after I posted it yesterday. I was just asking your opinion because of what you said. I will say this though, @Paulw11’s comment gave me enough info to lead on path to building my own Bonjour service. Had he not said that I would’ve never had idea to do that. Even though it got downvoted it helped me tremendously. I understand the coding part but I always saw it has as long as it helps a developer develop that’s what counts ‍♂️

Comment: That's why I didn't vote to close it.

Comment: @clearlight thanks, I appreciate it. Happy Coding 

Answer (score 0):

Using Bonjour there doesn't seem to be a limit. I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13717356/4833705). **eskimo** insinuated the same thing.

[image]